# Powershell and Xml tag removal

Tags: xml, powershell

I need to remove the **version** tag from the below xml.
I tried different options but not able to remove it.

$myXml.SelectNodes("//version") is not retrieving anything.

Solution might be simple but i am not able to achieve it.
Please help me in resolving it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.s.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>test</members>
        <name>testname</name>
    </types>
    <version>44.0</version>
</Package>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following.

```
$myXml.documentElement.removeChild($myXml.GetElementsByTagName("version")[0]);
```

It will remove the first **version** child node from the document.

Here is the output from before and after I removed the element.

[image]